# magento 1.9.1 please make sure your passwords match

Tags: magento

This is seems weird as when I check Mage model's customer class the method is there `getPasswordConfirmation()`, but when I check my extension files there is no any trace of such method or `getConfirmation()` method. But I get the above error as I try to place the order. Can you give me any suggestions or guesses? Help is appreciated. Thanks.

[extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/one-page-checkout-extension-fire-checkout-2-4.html)

Comment: Magento changed around version 1.9.1 the field to confirm password from `confirmation` to `password_confirmation`. If you do not use core files, which I suspect, you may want to adjust your logic based on the one you could find in `Mage_Customer_AccountController::resetPasswordPostAction()`

Answer (score 0):

It could be a JavaScript validation message generated from `validation.js` file:

In your `validation.js` file (probably around line 529) look for:

```
['validate-cpassword', 'Please make sure your passwords match.', function(v) {
```

If you don't want this validation just remove `validate-cpassword` (pay attention to letter **c** in cpassword!) from HTML class definition of your form in `.phtml` file (should be `billing.phtml`). In this line:

```
<input type="password" name="billing[confirm_password]" title="<?php echo $this->__('Confirm Password') ?>" id="billing:confirm_password" class="input-text required-entry validate-cpassword" />
```